# Setting modal image view?

Tags: iphone

In the Epic Win iPhone app, they seem to have some sort of image view in the front of another view. How does one implement this?

Example: [image: Epic Win App]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to create a new view and add it to the window. You can do that like this:

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.5];
[overlayView addSubview:<#imageView#>];
[self.view.window addSubview:overlayView];
[overlayView release];
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

From above example it seems that they just added Imageview on self.view and they decrease alpha of self.view. It doesn't seems something triky.

Answer (score 0):

That's very simple and there are probably a few ways to do it.

The simplest is probably to just add an image view as subview of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [`CustomAlert`](http://joris.kluivers.nl/iphone-dev/?p=CustomAlert) Class. Shows you how to change the background of a `UIAlertView`.